# Does iPad still use its battery when it is connected and fully charged?

Tags: ipad, battery, charging

I use my iPad on my desk with a stand everyday and it is connected to usb cable, which also charges iPad. It usually stays at 100% charge since my cable is connected.

In this case...does my iPad still use the battery? Does it still decrease lifespan of my iPad battery?

Answer (score -1):

No, the battery is not used once it is fully charged.

However, the battery life *is* getting depleted.  Keeping the battery charged at 100% keeps it at a high voltage, and this voltage is detrimental to the life of the battery.  This is the reason that Apple introduced an option to "Smart-charge" the battery to a lower percentage (80% is Apple's standard, but industry-wide 40% is a better choice).

Comment: Why is 40% better than 80%?

Comment: Because it's closer to 50% - Apple obviously chose 80% because people would be frustrated if their device didn't charge beyond 40% lol, and 80% achieves most of the same benefits

Comment: Why the down-vote?